# Yii2 using "AS variable" in sql query and display it in view

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

dear colleagues!
I have query:

```
$sql = "SELECT node.name,node.node_id,node.lft,(COUNT(prnt.name) - 1) AS depth
            FROM nested_category AS node,
            nested_category AS prnt 
            WHERE node.lft BETWEEN prnt.lft AND prnt.rgt 
            GROUP BY node.name
            ORDER BY node.lft";
                    $item = NodeMenu::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

I can display node.name like this:

```
foreach($item as $it =>$i)
    {
       echo $i->name;
    }
```

**The qestion is how can I display depth?**
When I'm trying to do the same as with node.name:

```
foreach($item as $it =>$i)
    {
       echo $i->depth;
    }
```

I get errorException: Array to string conversion.
print_r($item); doesn't contain depth.
Please help me out, I couldn't find the solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no variable or magic attribute `depth` in your model. Add one and it will be set when models are being populated from the result of the query.

```
class NodeMenu extends ... {
    public $depth;
```

Comment: Thank you! I only added  public $depth; and now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `as depth` you are naming the table produced by the `select` and not (COUNT(prnt.name) - 1).  You need this and  use d in your display instead of depth:

```
$sql = "SELECT node.name,node.node_id,node.lft,(COUNT(prnt.name) - 1)d AS depth
            FROM nested_category AS node,
            nested_category AS prnt 
            WHERE node.lft BETWEEN prnt.lft AND prnt.rgt 
            GROUP BY node.name
            ORDER BY node.lft";
                    $item = NodeMenu::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

Or you could just remove the as and keep your display statement the same:

```
$sql = "SELECT node.name,node.node_id,node.lft,(COUNT(prnt.name) - 1) depth
            FROM nested_category AS node,
            nested_category AS prnt 
            WHERE node.lft BETWEEN prnt.lft AND prnt.rgt 
            GROUP BY node.name
            ORDER BY node.lft";
                    $item = NodeMenu::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: when you get array with findBySql()->all() you get an array of ActiveRecord models. And your model does not have 'depth' attribute as it is dynamically added from sql query.
I think you've got two ways here:

1. Get array of plain db data using 'asArray()' method:

   ```
   $items = NodeMenu::findBySql($sql)->asArray()->all();
   foreach ($items as $item) {
      echo $item['depth'];
   }
   ```

   The negative side is: this will give you db data only but not models. Notice how we treat $item as array now.
2. If you need models you should only add 'depth' attribute into model class body:

   ```
   public $depth;
   ```

   That's all! All your other code will work fine. The negative side: if you want to add many calculated fields to sql query you have to fill your model with additional attributes you don't need elsewhere.